# I would like to audit an Ubuntu server to get a list of all files executed and all files read by the kernel

Tags: dpkg, audit

I want to be able to instrument and analyze at a prebuilt server and get a list of every file read.

I would also like to determine which of those files were read by the kernel to execute a program, load a library or just read by an application.

I thought it would be simple. SELinux by default deny, and in permissive mode, it logs everything. So, install it with no rules and run it in permissive mode and everything should be logged.

Note this question is related to [this one on Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/239436/281475) as I am experiencing something similar to that poster.
Then there is the issue that running under SELinux or any of the other auditing packages would introduce substantial load and possibly change the behavior of the system under observation.

Comment: Why SELinux when auditd would most likely do?

Comment: Because I don't want to "most likely", I want to definitely get the complete list.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you really trying to do? How will this list of files help? What about duplicates? What's a "prebuilt server"? Wouldn't `strace -e open ...` do it? `man strace`.

Comment: a prebuilt server:  a server someone else built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my particular investigation I realized I don't really care why the file was read whether it was read as an executable or configuration file doesn't matter to me at this point.
So I went back to find and found printf %T@ prints creation time and %A@ prints access time so if those are almost the same the file has not been modified since installation.
I'm still processing results but they look very promising.
I'm working with my team to get permission to open source the code but honestly the code is pretty straight forward.
I do recommend mounting with [lazytime](https://lwn.net/Articles/621046/) for best results

```
find_args=(-xdev -type f -printf "%p|%T@|%A@\\n")
find / $find_args > logfile.psv
```

#Create a PSV file (pipe seperated values file) that contains
#path|creation_time|access_time

Accomplishes what I want fairly reliably.  I tried using a straight CSV but some ubuntu firmware modules have a "," in thier name but I figured no one would be brave enough to ship a linux file with "|" in it's name so after some deliberation I settled on that.

One of the requirements for my application is 0 dependenceis so python based or perl based solutions don't work.

Combined with a simple "[package exploder](https://gist.github.com/biofool/49c1dc3d3a0d5b3bcabf69a3f2e567d1)" when we find a file that hasn't been used recently we can cross reference the installation package it came from

Comment: For an upvote, explain what your `find` options do, and why the ones you chose are important to solving the problem you faced.